# Vignette Table of Contents Missing When Package Published to CRAN

Tags: r, cran

I recently released a vignette with version 1.1 of my R package. The Rmd for the vignette can be found [here](https://github.com/eweine/qqconf/blob/master/qqconf/vignettes/qqconf_introduction.Rmd). When I create the vignette locally, I see author information and the table of contents at the top of the vignette, as expected. However, when I submitted this package to CRAN and the vignette was created [there](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/qqconf/vignettes/qqconf_introduction.html), I no longer see the table of contents or author information. Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: The output and session information when I create the vignette locally can be seen [here](https://github.com/eweine/qqconf/blob/master/qqconf/vignettes/qqconf_introduction.html)

Answer (score 2):

I glanced at your `DESCRIPTION` [here](https://github.com/eweine/qqconf/blob/master/qqconf/DESCRIPTION) and noticed that the `VignetteBuilder` field does not contain `rmarkdown`. Since you are using `knitr::rmarkdown` as an engine, I suspect that you need:

```
VignetteBuilder: knitr, rmarkdown
```

Here is a relevant paragraph from the [`R-exts`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file) manual:

> The `VignetteBuilder` field names (in a comma-separated list) packages that provide an engine for building vignettes. These may include the current package, or ones listed in `Depends`, `Suggests` or `Imports`. The `utils` package is always implicitly appended. See *Non-Sweave vignettes* for details. Note that if, for example, a vignette has engine `knitr::rmarkdown`, then `knitr` provides the engine but both `knitr` and `rmarkdown` are needed for using it, so both these packages need to be in the `VignetteBuilder` field and at least suggested (as `rmarkdown` is only suggested by `knitr`, and hence not available automatically along with it). Many packages using `knitr` also need the package `formatR` which it suggests and so the user package needs to do so too and include this in `VignetteBuilder`.

This is not a guaranteed fix, but it is maybe a first step.

Comment: Ah great, thank you! Are you aware of any way that I could test this without just submitting to CRAN again?

Comment: I don't know - sorry... It would certainly be convenient if `R CMD check` issued a note or warning in this situation.

Comment: Oh - I guess you could do `R CMD build`, unpack the tarball that you would otherwise submit to CRAN, then inspect the contents of `inst/doc/<whatever>.html`, to see if what was missing is now there.

Comment: I just tried these steps for myself, after cloning your repository and _without_ adding `rmarkdown` to `VignetteBuilder`, and I can't reproduce the issue. On my system, `R CMD build` builds the vignette correctly. Can you reproduce the issue on your end? Either way, you might consider reporting the problem to the R-package-devel mailing list. If you _can_ reproduce it, then there could be a bug in `R CMD build` or the vignette engine. If you _can't_ and the issue persists in future releases of your package, then there could be a glitch on CRAN's end.

Comment: Thanks for trying it on your own machine! Interestingly, the issue occurs on my machine in either case. I'm really not sure why it's happening. I tried using `devtools::build_vignettes` and the vignette builds as I intended. Should I try updating my version of R? I could also try releasing my package with `devtools::release` but I'm not sure if that would lead to a different outcome.

Comment: Yes, I suspect `VignetteBuilder` is a red herring here, though it is still best to comply with the manual and include `rmarkdown`. You should post to [R-package-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel) with your issue, including the steps you've tried so far and your system details (i.e., the first few lines of the output of `sessionInfo()`). There, you are more likely to get a response directly from a CRAN maintainer, who can better speak to whether there is a bug in `R CMD build` or the vignette engine.

Comment: You can certainly try updating R, `knitr`, and `rmarkdown`. I would not jump to re-releasing the package before getting advice from R-package-devel.

Comment: BTW, a similar issue was reported in a recent thread [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2021q4/007447.html).